# Delete dictionary from a list of dictionary if its key equals certain value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with two keys. I want to remove a dictionary from the list if its name key equals a certain value,Pam.

```
dict=[
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 20}
]
```

I know how to search through the dictionary:

```
(item for item in dicts if item["name"] == "Pam").next()
```

This will output the dictionaries that have Pam as the name key. So, instead of next I need something like del. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you actually need is something like this:

```
[item for item in mylist if item['name'] != 'Pam']
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is a good use for this, and don't call your variable `dict`:

```
list_of_dicts = filter(lambda x: x['name'] != 'Pam', list_of_dicts)
```

Or, even [`ifilterfalse`, from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> i = [
... {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
... {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
... {"name": "Pam", "age": 7},
... {"name": "Pam", "age": 20}
... ]
>>> list(itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x['name'] == 'Pam', i))
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'Mark'}]
>>> i = list(itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x['name'] == 'Pam', i))
>>> i
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'Mark'}]
```

Comment: Is this faster than the answer above yours?

Comment: If your list of dicts is very large, then go with the iterator option. Otherwise it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in dic:
  if dic.count(i) > 1:
    del i
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.